# Invalid API Key supplied using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Auth to allow users to sign up using Facebook. I have taken all the steps from here to implement sign up including adding *GoogleService-Info.plist* to my project.

I get the Facebook permission screen all fine but when the app hits

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
```

this error is returned: **An invalid API Key was supplied in the request.**

Can anyone help me with this please?

Thanks

Here is my function code to log in using Facebook.

```
@IBAction func signUpWithFacebook() {

    let fbLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

    fbLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController:self,  handler: {
        (result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Process error")
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            print("Cancelled");
        } else {
            print("Logged in");

            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(accessToken)
            print(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
                // ...
                if let user = user{
                    print(user.displayName)
                }
                else{

                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Solved it, for anyone that needs the solution in the future.

Sometimes *API_KEY* is missing from the GoogleService-Info.plist, this needs to be added.

The API Key can be found from Google API Console https://console.developers.google.com/

Comment: Hassan, glad your issue was resolved, but we'd like to investigate why the API key wasn't in your plist. 

Could you please drop us an email in our [support channel](https://support.google.com/firebase) mentioning this StackOverflow question, your plist and your project id?

Comment: just observed same behavior where the config file was missing API_KEY ... thanks for finding a fix for this issue!

Comment: I had this problem too - I just made sure everything was set up correctly and than generated the GoogleService-Info.plist again. The second one was correct.

Comment: This is now being reviewed by the Firebase Support Team

Comment: Although this is the solution I'd personally recommend downloading the plist file again. (Incase other settings change/missing)

Comment: very nice +1 added

Comment: Just had this exact problem. Re-downloading the plist fixed it.

Comment: I have same issue, and plist doesn't generate with API_KEY anymore, i changed some keys on console and created some others, but now the plist is always being generate without API_KEY, always.

Answer (score 15):

You can solve this by Downloading again the "GoogleService-Info.plist" file, under the Project Setting section on Firebase Console.

Ensure that the API_KEY is set on the new "GoogleService-Info.plist".

Comment: Downloading it again solved my problem... It's weird because I didn't make any changes to my project.

Comment: Yes this also solved my problem. Surprised that this still hasn't been fixed. Anyway thanks for the solution :-)

Comment: Like what @MXV Did :D :D
 Downloading it again solved my problem... It's weird because I didn't make any changes to my project.