# Firebase Authentication - Googlesheets "The request is missing a valid API key." Error 403

Tags: ios, firebase, google-sheets, firebase-authentication, google-sheets-api

When trying to connect a Firebase project to GoogleSheets I get an error

```
(lldb) po error
Error Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=403 "The request is missing a valid API key." UserInfo={GTLRStructuredError=GTLRErrorObject 0x61000005c650: {errors:[1] message:"The request is missing a valid API key." code:403 status:"PERMISSION_DENIED"}, NSLocalizedDescription=The request is missing a valid API key.}
```

Here is my code

```
let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesGet
  .query(withSpreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, range:range)
service.executeQuery(query,
                     delegate: self,
                     didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:))

func displayResultWithTicket(ticket: GTLRServiceTicket,
                           finishedWithObject result : GTLRSheets_ValueRange,
                           error : NSError?) {

if let error = error {
  showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
  return
}
```

I see a similar question [Invalid API Key supplied using Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37436352/1463518)

I enabled the  Google Sheets API at https://console.developers.google.com/
and refreshed the GoogleService-Info.plist. Deleted the app from simulator, reset simulator and added it back.

But I still get the error

I am using Using

- GoogleAPIClientForREST (1.2.1)
- FirebaseAuth (4.0.0)
- GTMOAuth2 (1.1.4)
- GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.10)

I am using scope kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheetsReadonly

I have not problem executing in the api explorer

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1o0kCH8As6Zx5q-n8KykaQS053ZkXMzLlc6PWiVnHipw?ranges=A1%3AB2&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I tried re-generating my api key and re-downloading the google.plist[image]

Comment: The sheets api require that you sent an authenticated request in case the data isn't public, otherwise it just needs the API key. Are you sure that the library you are using contains the necessary OAuth information?
Are you able to authenticate correctly in Firebase?
Can you use the library without using Firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this.

1. This had nothing to do with Firebase and was a GoogleAPIClientForREST issue
2. I had installed the GoogleAPIClientForREST (1.3.0) instead of 1.2.1
3. I was not passing **service.authorizer** with the **GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol** from **GIDGoogleUserauthentication fetcherAuthorizer()**

In 1.3.0 the service **no** longer has an authorizer I cannot find the documentation as to the correct way to execute this, so I reverted to 1.2.1

Googles documentation and quickstart is out of date

---------------------------------------------------------        **update**         -----------------------------------------------------

My response from GoogleSheets engineers is in the thread [groups.google.com/forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-objectivec-client/bNIipVqGz2c)

Add a bridging header if you do not have one with

```
  #import <GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.h>       
  #import <GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcherService.h>
```

This will resolve the issue for 1.3.0