# connecting to firestore emulator with @firebase/testing

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I am trying to test a firebase app locally.

I am running the test with `firebase emulators:exec --only firestore 'mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts`

In my spec, I import `@firebase/testing`  and setup my app and followed the directions from 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests

I have a `FirebaseService`  which is a singleton wrapper for my methods into which I inject my firebase app.
In production, I'll inject the firebase, and it gets initialized in the `FirebaseService` in testing, I initialize outside of the service.

The wrapper is fairly simple

```
export const FirebaseService = (function(): FirebaseSrvc {
  let firebase;
  const fbServiceObj: FirebaseSrvc = {
    getInstance: (firebaseConfig, firebaseCore, initialize) => {
      firebase = firebaseCore;
      if (initialize && firebase.apps.length === 0) {
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      }

      return fbServiceObj;
    },


    createActivity: async (title: string) => {
      try {
        const firebaseUid = firebase.auth().currentuser.uid;
        const newActivity: ActivityProps = {
          title,
          created_at: 123445,
          created_by: firebaseUid,
          public: false,
          available_to: [firebaseUid],
        };
        console.log(' before create', newActivity);
        const createResponse = await firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection('activities')
          .doc(stringToSafeId(title))
          .set(newActivity);
        console.log('create response', createResponse);
        return true;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error creating activity', e);
      }
    },

    getActivity: async (title: string): Promise<ActivityProps> => {
      try {
        const actResponse: DocumentReferenceTo<ActivityProps> = await firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection('activities')
          .doc(stringToSafeId(title))
          .get();
        return actResponse as ActivityProps;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error getting activity from firebase', e);
      }
    },
  };

  return fbServiceObj;
})();
```

The test I am attempting to run is

```
import * as firebase from '@firebase/testing';
import { assert } from 'chai';
import 'mocha';
import * as appConfig from '../../app-dev.json';
import { FirebaseService } from '../services/FirebaseService';

firebase.initializeTestApp({ ...appConfig.expo.extra.firebase, auth: { uid: 'random', email: 'test@test.com' } });


describe('Activity', async () => {
  const fb = FirebaseService.getInstance(appConfig.expo.extra.firebase, testApp, false);
  const activityData = new Activity(fb);
  beforeEach(async () => await firebase.clearFirestoreData({ projectId }));

  it('should create a new activity', async () => {
    await activityData.set('test-activity'); // this runs FirebaseService.createActivity
    const findActivity = await activityData.get('test-activity'); // this run FirebaseService.getActivity
    assert(findActivity.title === 'test-activity');
  });
});
```

When I run the test I get an error

```
Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.] {
  code: 'auth/invalid-api-key',
  message: 'Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.'
}
```

I can confirm that the API key which is passed into `firebase.initializeTestApp` matches the Web API Key in my firebase console.

I have also downloaded the google-services.json from my firebase console and lists

```
{
 "api_key": [
  { "current_key": different_from_web_key}
  ]
}
```

And I have replaced my existing key with this new key, I still get the same error.
I have also tried setting up  `initializeTestApp({ projectId })` which is how the example from firebase docs sets it up, and I receive the same result.

I am using the same project details to run a project locally in android studio, and I am able to authenticate and write to firestore, so the API key I am using does work, but it appears to have issues being used in the test app.

Answer (score -2):

This usually doesn't have a specific way to solve it. It might be that even a new copy and paste of the API key to the parameters, might make it work and the error to disappear.

I would recommend you to take a look at the following posts from the Community, that have some possible fixes for the error that you are facing.

- [Firebase Error: auth/invalid-api-key, Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/61)
- [Invalid API Key supplied using Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436352/invalid-api-key-supplied-using-firebase)

In addition to that, since Firebase has free support offers, I think you reaching out to the [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) would help you fix this quickly. You should be able to contact directly [for free](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: All the links point to mistakes using regular Firebases's `initializeApp`. The problem here is when using `initializeTestApp` from `@firebase/testing`. In this scenario I can't understand why the API key could be a problem. Also, the API doesn't even receive an API key.